# List View - XSLT Filter by Count

Tags: list, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a SharePoint list that has several records.  One field in the list uses SPServices to query possible values in another list during data entry (essentially a lookup).

I created a view and am looking at customizing the XSLT so that I only show records where the lookup field mentioned above appears more than once.  For example, say I have a simple list:

```
ID    Location
===============
1     123
2     123
3     456
```

I want to create a view where the only items that are displayed are ID#1 and #2 because the location appears multiple times.

If a new item (#4) is added and it contains a location of 123, #4 should now appear in this view, but #3 should still be excluded.

```
ID    Location
===============
1     123
2     123
3     456
4     123
```

Instead, if #4 had a location of 456, all entries should display (preferrably grouped) in the view.

```
ID    Location
===============
1     123
2     123
3     456
4     456
```

So I am assuming that 1) I need to do a count for each location, 2) assign a count for each entry in the list and 3) filter on the count field where greater than one.  I am just not sure where to start here.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you include the XSLT that you have written so far? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused since the code that you mentioned is not valid XSLT or XPath.

Comment: I added Conditional Formatting on the row, which hides the rows succesfully. But I would also like to hide the header as well. The condition I am using is the following:  

CONDITION: count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Location1=$thisNode/@Location1])<2
FORMATTING: Display:None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it is working all of a sudden (maybe  my own syntax), but I was able to hide group headers with XSLT by wrapping the **td** tag in a **xsl:if** block.

```
 <xsl:template name="GroupHeader" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="fieldtitle" />
    <xsl:param name="fieldname" />
    <xsl:param name="group" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="fieldtype" />
    <xsl:param name="groupid" />
    <xsl:param name="groupindex" />
    <xsl:param name="groupindex2" />
    <xsl:param name="imagesrc" />
    <xsl:param name="alttext" />
    <xsl:param name="altname" />
    <xsl:param name="RowCount" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Collapse"/>
<tbody id="titl{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" groupString="{@*[name()=concat($fieldtitle, '.urlencoded')]}">
    <xsl:if test="$Collapse">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:none</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <tr id="group{$groupid}">
  <!-- CHANGE HERE -->
  <xsl:if test="$RowCount &gt; 1">
 <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" style="height: 19px">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$groupid='0' or $groupid='9'">ms-gb</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>ms-gb2</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$groupid='0' or $groupid='9'">
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$groupid='1'">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" height="1" width="10"/>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" height="1" width="20"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$NoAJAX or $InlineEdit">
          <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, true);return false;">
            <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" id="img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname" />
          </a>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}', 'img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}',event, false);return false;">
            <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" id="img_{$ViewCounter}-{$groupindex}{$groupindex2}" />
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldname" />
          </a>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="$fieldname"> : </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='Number' or $fieldtype='Currency'">
          <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=$fieldtitle]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$fieldtype ='DateTime'">
          <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=concat($fieldtitle, '.groupdisp')]"/>              
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='User' or $fieldtype='UserMulti'">
          <xsl:value-of select="@*[name()=concat($fieldtitle, '.span')]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="PrintField" select="$group">
            <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="."/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      <span style="font-weight: lighter;display: inline-block;">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$XmlDefinition/List/@Direction='rtl' or $LCID='1037'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#8207;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#8206;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>(<xsl:value-of select="$RowCount"/>)
      </span>
    </td>
    </xsl:if>
  </tr>
```